# How do I access MongoDB from EmberJS?

Tags: ember.js

Every tutorial and guide show I need another framework such as Express, Angular, Sails, or Koa to connect with MongoDB.

Do I need to learn how to write Middleware, Adapters, and more to get MongoDB to work with EmberJS?

I'm pretty new, and I just finished a simple to-do and web scraping apps. I want to learn how to store it like how I can just write python script, process data, connect to postgresql, save data to the database server.

Can you provide a link to the right source, a step by step process, or tools to research that can help anyone in my position now and in the future learn how to make EmberJS and MongoDB work together without going in circles?

I use nodejs, emberjs, mongodb hosted on heroku.

Comment: I don't know Ember,  but on the server side you'll need something to convert your commands into something Mongo can understand. Typically this is a script that accepts an action request and a cookie/auth token (over HTTP) and performs the action on Mongo (e.g. insert a document) if the cookie is correct. Often this uses JSON going in and going out. So if you want to stick with JS, then yes Express is a good approach.